# Retrieving information if there is one location in the list

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a task table linked to a task list table. In addition, I have a location table linked to the task table.
I would like to associate the entire list of tasks with user A using the @EMPID variable.
Conditions:

- I'm supposed to associate tasks that are in AA location.
  Assuming there is another position in the same list, I have to skip the line with the non-AA position in the task list and go to the next line in the same list.
- Assuming there is a user in the list who is not A, skip the entire list and go to the next list.

I wrote this using a procedure in which there is a cursor. I need the cursor to skip the rows and tasks that do not meet the conditions, and finally allocate the list of tasks.
task table:

[image]

task list table:

[image]

location table:

[image]

expected results:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE assign
(
    @usrid int
)    
AS
    DECLARE @empid int
    DECLARE @tklid int
    DECLARE @check int
    DECLARE @cnt int
                     
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT tkl_ID
        FROM tasklist
        INNER JOIN lv_task ON tsk_tasklistid = tkl_id 
        INNER JOIN lv_location ON tsk_location = location_code
            WHERE location_code = a tkl_id ) x ON tkl_ID = x.TKLID
        WHERE tkl_locationcode = a
         
    OPEN c_tasklist
    FETCH c_tasklist INTO @tklid
    WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
    BEGIN        
        UPDATE task SET
            tsk_user = @empid
        WHERE tsk_user IS NULL 
        AND tsk_id IN (SELECT tsk id FROM task WHERE tsk_location = 'AA'
    END
```

I'm not in the right direction yet, I'd appreciate guidance, thanks!

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your schema, post your DDL. Your `create table` statements, with primary keys and foreign keys. It is *much* easier for people reading your question to understand the relationships. It also means if we want to help you out we can copy-paste your code to create your schema on our systems and author some queries. It's even better if you include `insert` statements with sample data. Posting images means we have to flick back and forth between your question and our SQL windows. People will just think "not worth the effort" and move on to the next question.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Developing a consistent style and layout is highly important for writing maintainable SQL. Choose your preferred casing and indenting and then stick to it.

Comment: Also you code above doesn't even compile, there are missing brackets, and maybe a missing sub-query. At least sort that out before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a cursor at all:

`UPDATE task SET tsk_user = 'A' WHERE tsk_location = 'AA' AND tsk_user = ''`